# How to select a specific part of text in HTML and convert it to uppercase using regexp?

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext, uppercase

I'm trying to figure out how to select a specific part of text in HTML and convert it to uppercase using regexp in Sublime Text. An example of HTML that I have:

```
<p><b>Lorem ipsum / Dolor Sit Amet -- consectetur -- adipiscing</b><br> [...]

<p><b>elit -- "sed" -- do -- eiusmod</b><br>  [...]

<p><b>Tempor, Incididunt & ut labore -- "et" -- dolore -- magna</b><br>  [...]
```

I need to select everything between the tags `<p><b>` and the first appearance of `--` and convert it to uppercase, like this:

```
<p><b>LOREM IPSUM / DOLOR SIT AMET -- consectetur -- adipiscing</b><br> [...]

<p><b>ELIT -- "sed" -- do -- eiusmod</b><br>  [...]

<p><b>TEMPOR, INCIDIDUNT & UT LABORE -- "et" -- dolore -- magna</b><br>  [...]
```

Could you please help me to solve this? I'm new to regexp and still don't really understand it's complexity... Thanks!

Comment: Obligatory link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags – TL;DR: do not try to parse HTML with regular expressions ;)

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks :)

Comment: Try `<p><b>\K[^<>]*?--` and replace with `\U$0`

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you! So after all, one can use regular expressions to parse some HTML.